# ReportViewer Conditional Formatting

Tags: winforms, conditional-statements, reportviewer

I am trying to apply conditional formatting of certain table cells in my ReportViewer control.  I understand how to apply conditions by comparing data that resides in the same row, for example, the following will color a cell RED if the Cost is higher than the revenue:

```
=IIf(Fields!Cost.Value > Fields!Revenue.Value, "Red", "Black")
```

My issue is that I need to compare data to the previous row.  My requirement is to flag a table cell that changed from the previous entry.  For example:

```
TableRow 1:    Fred,   23,  Boat
TableRow 2:    Fred,   67,  Boat     ** 67 needs to be flagged
```

How would one go about doing this using a conditional statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone is interested in the answer, I found a solution.
There is a Previous function that is built into reportviewer, that I just found.

Previous(Fields!LineTotal.Value)

It returns the previous row data.  This will do what I need.

Comment: how did you get it to change color based on the condition? I'm using ReportViewer 05 for ASP.NET - I'm assuming it would be something similar to what you've written but I get an #Error when specifying colors like you did "Red", "Black"

Comment: You need to set the BackgroundColor property.  What is the IIF statement you are using?  There may be a logical error in it.  One thing to look for, is that the color name needs to be a string, so you may need to put double quotes around them.